# Java dateFormat Unparseable date exception

Tags: java

I am facing an issue while converting the date I recieve in a json object to its required format. The date i get from back end is `Apr-13, Wednesday, 04:06:00 PM`. This is what I have done.

```
String refreshDateString = jobj.optString("refresh_date").toString();
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd, EEEE  hh:mm:ss a");
Date refreshDate = parseFormat.parse(refreshDateString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", ""));
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, E, hh:mm a");
```

I have also tried Using a single E instead of EEEE. Any inputs on where I am wrong? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also I would suggest you to use JodaTime library or newest version of Date API included to Java 8 (which is actually copy and paste of JodaTime). Since it's much better to work with dates. So to parse a String of given format there will looks like

```
String string = "Apr-13, Wednesday, 04:06:00 PM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM-dd, E, hh:mm:ss a");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

If you have lots of dates conversions etc. in your code it's just must have for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `,` after the Day name in week and you should use `E` instead of `EEEE`, use this format

```
DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd, E, hh:mm:ss a");
```

If you dont have a `,` after the Day name in week; you have extra space between `EEEE` and `hh` `EEEE  hh:mm:ss`. Use this instead

```
DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd, E hh:mm:ss a");
```

Comment: Not getting a comma from backend , Sorry! This is how it looks 
Apr-13, Wednesday 04:06:00 PM

Comment: Thanks a Ton! I seemed to have overlooked the space :D

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional space and comma missing on your pattern. One important thing though is the Locale if your system is in a different language than the date you are receiving:

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd, EEEE, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
```

In my case, since my machine is in Italian, without locale I will never be able to parse the given date.